# Matlab Interpolation of 4D matrix

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I would like to interpolate 4D matrix.
The matrix size is 400X200X400X200 of complex numbers.
Im using the function: interpn

And for that I have to set set my new grid by using:
ndgrid

But ndgrid  takes hours.
Can you please help?

Thanks!

Sample code:

```
[Y X V U]=ndgrid (ky_vec,kx_vec,kv_vec,ku_vec);
F=f(Y,X,V,U);
[Yt Xt Vt Ut]=ndgrid (ky_vec,kx_vec,ky_vec,kx_vec,'single');
A=interpn(Y,X,V,U,F,0.9*Yt,0.9*Xt,(1-0.9)*Vt,(1-0.9)*Ut,'linear',0.0);
```

Comment: Please post a MWE. What are `ky_vec`, `kx_vec`,`kv_vec`,`ku_vec`, `f`?

Comment: Wait? If you already have `f`, why would you even want to do interpolation? Isn't `f` a function? You really need to clarify on your actual problem, this doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: @kndelsepp Maybe `f` takes even longer and interpolation is regarded as faster operation? Anyway we are taling about billions of points of course this takes very long. The question should be clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'single'` argument doesn't belong there. It is interpreted as `ones(1,length('single'))` instead and thus yields even huger matrices.

You could also generate a `griddedInterpolant` instead, which would save memory:

```
 F_interp = griddedInterpolant({ky_vec,kx_vec,kv_vec,ku_vec},F)
```

Comment: That was the solution, Thanks!

Comment: @user1112136: If you think this answer is the solution to your problem, please accept it by clicking the grey check mark next to it.